# Create a login form with enable/disable button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I learned how to have a textbox and when the value is empty the button is disabled and when I enter a value in the textbox the button is enabled.

Now I want to have a login form that contains one textbox (for username) and another textbox (for password), so here I learned how to code.
But how should I write the code so that when the condition (both text boxes are empty) the button is disabled and when the condition is (both text boxes have values) the button is enabled.

Comment: Edit the post and add the code that you already have. You probably should read this article about logical operations anyway: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators

Comment: TextBox has a Text changed event. You need to add that event handler and check if both textboxes has text, if then enable the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void txtUserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckFields();
    }

    private void txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckFields();
    }

    private void CheckFields()
    {
        btnLogin.Enabled = txtPassword.Text.Length == 0 || txtUserName.Text.Length == 0 ? false : true;
    }
```

I assume that your `username` textbox is named, `txtUserName`, and your `password` textbox is named, `txtPassword`. Also the `login` button is named, `btnLogin`. I recommend setting the `btnLogin` enabled property to `false` when the form first loads. You can set that in the form's `Load` event:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnLogin.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: I would tend to disable the Button by default in the designer, so no code required on the Load event. Also, you can use the same method to handle both TextChanged events if the code for both will be the same.

Comment: Also, while using an if statement is not wrong, given that you're signing a bool anyway, you can just assign the Boolean expression directly, rather than trading it with the if statement and then assigning a literal.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the TextChanged event for both boxes and have it be something like this:

```
private void CheckTextboxes(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUsername.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPassword.Text)) 
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
            return;
        }
        button.Enabled = true;
    }

private void txtUsername_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckTextboxes();
    }

private void txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckTextboxes();
    }
```

That way you ensure that if the user enters values on the textboxes in either order the button only enables if both have actual text written on them.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you implement this logic on the client side (javascript), it is unnecessary to go to the server again and again for every text change.

you should add onclick function on username and password textboxes and implement the logic to check whether both have values then enable the button else disable it.